# What font is used in the SGS ISO logos?

Tags: vector, font-identification, logo

I am trying to generate a vector image of the SGS ISO 9001:2000 certification logo. I have a vector for the SGS ISO 14001 logo (attached here) but the text is not in editable format...the designer converted the text to paths.

Ideally, if someone knows where I can obtain a vector of the SGS ISO 27001 logo, or any SGS Logo with editable text (not converted to paths), that would be best. However, if that is not available, I would appreciate if someone could help me identify the font.

The only part of the logo that needs to be changed is the orange text **9001:2000**. The **ISO** and the remainder of the logo elements are shared between the various different certifications.

[image]

Comment: you can find this logo in a vector format in the following [link](http://seeklogo.com/search.html?q=SGS)

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to modify an existing logo? ".. you are not allowed to use ISO’s logo, which is copyrighted. ISO will take whatever actions it considers necessary to prevent the misuse of its logo." - http://www.iso.org/iso/publicizing_iso9001_iso14001_certification_2010.pdf

Comment: @Jongware I do not intend to modify it. My client is SGS ISO certified, but they don't have the current certification mark. I have reached out to SGS to request the correct mark, but while waiting for them to respond, I need to put the logo on the dev site. The client has objected to using the outdated ISO 9001:2000 (current is 9001:2008) which is what they have, and they do not have the ISO/IEC 27001. I suggested using placeholders until SGS responds, but they seem to have a stick up their behind about that. As such, there is no copyright issues or misuse.

Comment: @hsawires That site does not have the ISO/IEC 27001 logo, and the ISO 9001:2000 is outdated (current mark is ISO 9001:2008). The type has been converted to paths and as such cannot be easily updated to the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a lot like Arial Condensed. If it's just a placeholder until you can get an officially sanctioned logo Arial Condensed will probably suffice.